# Buildozer error: ./distribute.sh -l How to solve?

Tags: python, buildozer

I'm triying to make an android app using python and kivy. I've set up the virtualbox manager and installed buildozer. When I try to create an apk though, I get the following error. What is going wrong?

```
# Command failed: /usr/bin/python -m pip install -q --user 'appdirs' 'colorama>=0.3.3' 'jinja2' 'six' 'enum34; python_version<"3.4"' 'sh>=1.10; sys_platform!="nt"' 'pep517<0.7.0"' 'pytoml' 'virtualenv'
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     LC_NUMERIC = 'fr_FR.UTF-8'
#     _LXSESSION_PID = '1373'
#     XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR = '/var/lib/lightdm-data/kivy'
#     QT4_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
#     UPSTART_EVENTS = 'started xsession'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     LC_PAPER = 'fr_FR.UTF-8'
#     LOGNAME = 'kivy'
#     USER = 'kivy'
#     HOME = '/home/kivy'
#     XDG_VTNR = '7'
#     PATH = '/home/kivy/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games'
#     DISPLAY = ':0'
#     SSH_AGENT_PID = '1329'
#     LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     TERM = 'xterm'
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     XDG_SESSION_PATH = '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/home/kivy/.Xauthority'
#     LANGUAGE = 'en_US'
#     INSTANCE = ''
#     LC_MONETARY = 'fr_FR.UTF-8'
#     MANDATORY_PATH = '/usr/share/gconf/Lubuntu.mandatory.path'
#     JOB = 'dbus'
#     TEXTDOMAIN = 'im-config'
#     UPSTART_INSTANCE = ''
#     CLUTTER_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
#     SESSION = 'Lubuntu'
#     SESSIONTYPE = 'lxsession'
#     XMODIFIERS = '@im=ibus'
#     SELINUX_INIT = 'YES'
#     XDG_CONFIG_HOME = '/home/kivy/.config'
#     SAL_USE_VCLPLUGIN = 'gtk'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
#     GTK_IM_MODULE = 'xim'
#     LC_ADDRESS = 'fr_FR.UTF-8'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/tmp/ssh-7voncPxsXV4e/agent.1326'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     GDMSESSION = 'Lubuntu'
#     IM_CONFIG_PHASE = '1'
#     UPSTART_JOB = 'lxsession'
#     TEXTDOMAINDIR = '/usr/share/locale/'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/lubuntu:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/usr/share/gdm:/var/lib/menu-xdg:/usr/share/Lubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/'
#     XDG_SEAT_PATH = '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'LXDE'
#     XDG_SESSION_ID = 'c1'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-QJjucDwE84'
#     _ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
#     LC_IDENTIFICATION = 'fr_FR.UTF-8'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'Lubuntu'
#     UPSTART_SESSION = 'unix:abstract=/com/ubuntu/upstart-session/1000/1204'
#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/lubuntu:/etc/xdg/xdg-Lubuntu:/usr/share/upstart/xdg:/etc/xdg'
#     DEFAULTS_PATH = '/usr/share/gconf/Lubuntu.default.path'
#     GDM_LANG = 'en_US'
#     LC_TELEPHONE = 'fr_FR.UTF-8'
#     LC_MEASUREMENT = 'fr_FR.UTF-8'
#     PWD = '/home/kivy'
#     SSH_AGENT_LAUNCHER = 'upstart'
#     LC_NAME = 'fr_FR.UTF-8'
#     XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'lxde-'
#     LC_TIME = 'fr_FR.UTF-8'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.axv=01;35:*.anx=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.axa=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:'
#     XDG_SEAT = 'seat0'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# If the error is not obvious, please raise the log_level to 2
# and retry the latest command.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

This is my first time using Ubunta so I'm not very advanced here. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!